# Проверка работы со стилями на сайте (Bootstrap, JQuery)

Tags: css3, вёрстка, bootstrap, тестирование

На сайте, где размещается контент, скрипты из футера меняют стили основных элементов бутстрапа размещенного контента, в связи с чем ищу проверочный одностраничник в котором эти элементы были бы расположены, чтобы разместить код  на сайт и посмотреть, какой будет computed style. Задаю вопрос, потом что думаю, что писать такую hmtl страничку самому - это типа велосипед мастерить.  Подскажите,  такую страницу для тестирования, где взять?

Comment: Прочел Ваш текст, но вопроса не увидел.

Comment: Замечание по форме принято, знак вопроса добавлен.

Comment: Теперь лучше код в вопрос добавить.